# Como atualizar um arquivo XML sem recarregar a página

Tags: javascript, cache, xmlhttprequest

Boa tarde, estou criando uma aplicação que carrega funções com base nas informações de um determinado arquivo XML. No entanto, assim que salvo uma nova função via php, quando vou fazer uma XHttpRequest em javascript o códigco continua o mesmo. Eu já tentei utilizar o requestHeader("cache-control", "no-cache") mas ainda estou tendo problemas. Alguém conhece uma solução para meu problema? Eu estou usando o cache-control de forma indevida?  Qualquer ajuda é apreciada

EDIT: Resolvido conforme na resposta, descobri o que eu estava fazendo de errado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cache-control não pode ser usada em requests, somente em responses, você pode criar um arquivo php que retorne o seu arquivo xml toda vez que for chamado. Veja o código abaixo:

```
$xmlfile = file_get_contents ( "myfile.xml" );
header ( "Cache-Control: no-cache" );
header ( "Pragma: no-cache" );
header ( "Content-type: text/xml" );
echo $xmlfile;
```

Desse modo você pode retornar o arquivo e toda vez que uma request nova for feita, não será utilizado cache.